# Deezer API endpoint with details about parnter/co-branded subscription

Tags: deezer

I'm looking for Deezer API endpoint returning info about subscription via partner and/or co-branding detail.
For example, similar data as available on https://www.deezer.com when signed in with an account subscribed with a partner/co-branding options (available in included javascript):

```
var CUSTO = {
                "id":0,
                "logos": { 
                    "header":"logo_telekomslovenije_trans-v00341265",
                    "logo_link":"",
                    "logo_position":"bottom"
                },
                "tab_header":{ 
                    "name":"",
                    "color":"",
                    "url":"",
                    "iframe_url":"",
                    "iframe_height":760,
                    "iframe_width":"990px"
                },
                "store_platform":"deezer"
            };

var COBRANDING = 'none';
```

Additionally it might be handy if available subscription **INFOS** / **offers** http://api.deezer.com/infos would also contain partner/co-branded subscription options for given country of unsubscribed (free) user.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, these endpoints do not exist and will not be implemented, sorry.